# Expressjs - next(false) against return;

Tags: node.js, express

Is there a benefit by calling `return next(false)` in order to break the middleware chain? because I can just write `return res.send('')` which will break the chain also. Is there a difference between those approaches?

Answer (score 1):

By looking in the source code, you can see that:

- [`next(false)`](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/508936853a6e311099c9985d4c11a4b1b8f6af07/lib/router/index.js#L176-L320=) in the router index.js script has a just few if-else statements
- [`res.send('')`](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/508936853a6e311099c9985d4c11a4b1b8f6af07/lib/response.js#L107-L225=) is somewhat longer and more complex (it has more if/else branches) than [`next(false)`](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/508936853a6e311099c9985d4c11a4b1b8f6af07/lib/router/index.js#L176-L320=)
- `res.end()` is way faster than the other two, as it uses the [http module built-in function](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding_callback)

Express [response extends the http built-in response](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/508936853a6e311099c9985d4c11a4b1b8f6af07/lib/response.js#L42) in case you're wondering :)